# OLS predict using only a subset of explanatory variables

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Say I do an OLS regression using statsmodels of variable `y` on some explanatory variables `x1 x2 x3` (contained in a dataframe `df`):

```
res = smf.ols('y ~ x1 + x2 + x3', data=df).fit()
```

Is it possible to get a predicted value using only a subset of the explanatory variables? For example, I would like to get a predicted value for the observations in `df` using only `x1` and `x2` but not `x3`.

I have tried to do

```
res.predict(df[['x1','x2']])
```

but I get the error message: `NameError: name 'x3' is not defined`.

**Edit**: The reason I want to do this is the following. I'm running a regression of house values on house characteristics and dummies for metropolitan area, suburban status, and year. I would like to use the dummies for metropolitan area, suburban status and year to construct a price index for each location and time period.

**Edit 2**: This is how I ended up doing it, in case it can be helpful to anyone or someone can point me to a better way of doing it.

I'm interested in doing an OLS on the following specification:

```
model = 'price ~ C(MetroArea) + C(City) + C(Year) + x1 + ... + xK'
```

where `'x1 + ... + xK'` is pseudo-code for a bunch of variables I'm using as controls but I'm not interested in, and the categorical variables are very large (e.g. 90 Metropolitan areas).

Next I fit the model with statsmodels and construct the design matrix that I'll use to predict prices using the variables of interest.

```
res = smf.ols(model, data=mydata).fit()

data_prediction = mydata[['MetroArea','City','Year']]
model_predict = 'C(MetroArea) + C(City) + C(Year)'
X = patsy.dmatrix(model_predict, data=data_prediction, return_type='dataframe')
```

The tricky part now is to select the right parameters for the variables of interest, since there are many and their names are not exactly those of their respective variables since I've used the categorical operator, `C()`, of patsy (e.g. variables for MetroArea look like: `C(MetroArea)[0]`, `C(MetroArea)[8]`, ...).

```
vars_interest = ['Intercept', 'MetroArea', 'City', 'Year']
params_interest = res.params[[any([word in var for word in vars_interest]) 
                                for var in res.params.index]]
```

Get prediction by doing the dot product of the selected parameters and variables of interest:

```
prediction = np.dot(X,params_interest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles on this old question, there seems to be a cleaner solution using the information contained in the design matrix.

```
import numpy as np
from patsy import dmatrices
import statsmodels.api as sm

mydata = None
vars_of_interest = ['C(MetroArea)', 'C(City)', 'C(Year)']
formula = 'price ~' + " + ".join(vars_of_interest) + ' + x1 + ... + xK'
Y, X = dmatrices(formula, mydata)
# Get the slice names from patsy
slices = X.design_info.term_name_slices
model = sm.OLS(Y, X)
res = model.fit()

prediction = np.zeros(X.shape[0])
for var in vars_of_interest:
    prediction += X[:, slices[var]].dot(res.params[slices[var]])
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do **conceptually?** When you predict using your regression you're just plugging values into an equation. So predicting "without `x3`" is the same as just plugging in x3=0.

In terms of implementing this, it looks like statsmodels is pretty draconian about prediction using the same variable names as you used during a fit. So this is not elegant, but works:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['x3'] = 0
res.predict(df2[['x1','x2','x3']])
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it gets very inconvenient when `x3` is a large vector of control variables, and when `df` is a large dataset.

Comment: I don't think supporting this in predict makes sense. You should just do the dot product yourself, if you want to do this. You'll need to pass the constant explicitly in X though.

Comment: prediction for OLS (linear model) is just `x dot params`, so you can select the relevant columns of x and the corresponding elements of the params vector.

Comment: I have hundreds of parameters I want to use in my prediction, one for each metropolitan area, plus the ones for the year dummies and suburban status. Then there are all the parameters of the control variables that I don't want to use in the prediction. Implementing the dot product manually is quite a hassle.

Comment: Why would it be anymore of hassle than slicing? `cols = ['x1', 'x2', 'x2']; np.dot(df[cols], res.params[cols])`

Comment: When I run my model in statsmodels I use some of patsy's operators, like C( ), which make the names of the coefficients different from the ones of their corresponding variables. I edited my question with my work around this problem, but it isn't very pretty.